# Mlperf v2.0 Habana Bert Training on Aws Gaudi1

Tags: training-data, bert-language-model

I need to run MLPerf 2.0 Bert training code on Intel-Habana Gaudi1 processor on Aws with image Deep Learning AMI Habana PyTorch 1.12.0 SynapseAI 1.6.0 (Ubuntu 20.04) 20220928. Followed below readme

```
Readme: https://github.com/mlcommons/training_results_v2.0/tree/main/Intel-HabanaLabs/benchmarks
Dataset : https://github.com/mlcommons/training/tree/master/language_model/tensorflow/bert#download-and-preprocess-datasets
VM: Aws Deep Learning AMI Habana PyTorch 1.12.0 SynapseAI 1.6.0 (Ubuntu 20.04) 20220928 Guaid1 VM, RAM - 742GB and 96core
```

I've challenges in converting datasets into tf_records, packing script pack_pretraining_data_tfrec never succeeded due memory issue

To convert tf_records with unzipped dataset results_text.zip, when I ran `pretraining/create_pretraining_data.py` with `--input_file=/root/datasets/results4/part-0000*` option it tooks almost all the available 742GB memory and swap.

so, I converted each part file into tf_record using for loop.

To use packed method in training, I used script `pack_pretraining_data_tfrec.py` to covert tf_records with --max-files option 10 files (default 100), but looks like script load all tf_records into memory sequentially before start pack to create strategy files, hence fill-up all available 742 memory and failed pack.

Hence I tried with Unpacked method, for that I converted tf_records into binary file using script record_to_binary script from GraphCore v1.0 submission,
(https://github.com/mlcommons/training_results_v1.0/tree/master/Graphcore/benchmarks/bert/implementations/popart/bert_data)

When i run training process, getting below errors

```
1/ getting corrupt data error.

2/ [1,0]<stderr>:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1396, in _do_call
[1,0]<stderr>:    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
[1,0]<stderr>:tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
[1,0]<stderr>:
[1,0]<stderr>:2 root error(s) found.
[1,0]<stderr>:  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Key: masked_lm_ids.  Can't parse serialized Example.
[1,0]<stderr>:   [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]
[1,0]<stderr>:   [[IteratorGetNext]]
[1,0]<stderr>:   [[IteratorGetNext/_10085]]
[1,0]<stderr>:  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Key: masked_lm_ids.  Can't parse serialized Example.
[1,0]<stderr>:   [[{{node ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]
[1,0]<stderr>:   [[IteratorGetNext]]
[1,0]<stderr>:0 successful operations.
[1,0]<stderr>:0 derived errors ignored.
```

Questions: Is it right procedure to convert
1/ first dataset part file into tf_records one at time.
2/ convert tf_records part-000* into binary file? can the resulted part-*** can be used for unpacked method?
3/ how to limit max-files to 10 or 25 files in packing pack_pretraining_data_tfrec.py script?

Please advise if there are any alternative method to pack Bert wiki dataset for Mlperf v2.0 Bert Training for Gaudi.